Facing error when verify using Hardhat ignition
Someone can you help me, I deployed smart contract on Sepolia_Eth, and I want to verifying using hardhat-ignition.
npx hardhat ignition verify chain-11155111

But I get the error.
Error in plugin @nomicfoundation/hardhat-ignition: No etherscan API key configured for network sepolia

Here my hardhat.config.js I have to using CustomChains or not I dont know.
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: [process.env.PRIVATE_KEY],

    customChains: [
      {
        network: 'sepolia',
        chainId: 11155111,
        urls: {
          apiKey: process.env.ETHEREUM_API_KEY,
          apiURL: 'https://api-sepolia.etherscan.io/api',
          browserURL: 'https://sepolia.etherscan.io',
        },
      },
    ],
  },

How Ican solve this error


You can try this, works for me!

import { HardhatUserConfig } from "hardhat/config";
import "@nomicfoundation/hardhat-toolbox";
import "dotenv/config";

const PRIVATE_KEY = process.env.PRIVATE_KEY;
const API_KEY_ETHERSCAN = process.env.API_KEY_ETHERSCAN;
const API_KEY_BSC = process.env.API_KEY_BSC;

const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
  solidity: "0.8.24",
  networks: {
    sepolia: {
      url: "https://eth-sepolia.public.blastapi.io",
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY ? PRIVATE_KEY : ""],
    },
    bscTestnet: {
      url: "https://bsc-testnet-rpc.publicnode.com",
      accounts: [PRIVATE_KEY ? PRIVATE_KEY : ""],
    },
 },
  etherscan: {
    apiKey: {
      sepolia: API_KEY_ETHERSCAN ? API_KEY_ETHERSCAN : "",
      bscTestnet: API_KEY_BSC ? API_KEY_BSC : "",
    },
  },
  sourcify: { enabled: false },
};

export default config;

